# How to know the most recent date out of three using if...else statements

Tags: java, date, netbeans

I'm trying to finish a Java program that has been assigned to me by my teacher where I'm being asked to come up with different calculations regarding the usage of 3 telephone booths, each one of them owned by different service providers.

One of the program's requirements is to show in which one of the booths has the most recent call been done relying solely on the calling date. In order to do so, I've set up variables for the dates of the three booth's calls: day (DD), month (MM) and year (YYYY). How should I compare these three dates to print the name of the service provider which booth has been used the latest?

```
 if ((yyyyverizon>=yyyysprint)&&(yyyyverizon>=yyyyatt)){
  if ((mmverizon>=mmsprint)&&(mmverizon>=mmatt)){
   if((ddverizon>=ddsprint)&&(ddverizon>=ddatt)){
    System.out.println("Most recent call has been done through Verizon's booth");}}}
```

Guess if done this way it's necessary to do various if-else statements as the latest call could've been done in any of those three

I really appreciate any help you can provide!

Comment: id recommend adding the telephone booths to some sort of array, and iterate through them. You can compare year first, then month, then day, and return the most recent booth based on this algorithm

Comment: Hints: `java.time.LocalDate`, `java.util.ArrayList`, `java.lang.Enum`, and roll your own class. Also, **this is too broad a question** for this site. Stack Overflow is for narrowly-focused questions on a specific programming issue. “How to do my homework” is not appropriate.

Comment: Why cant you convert it to actual date objects by concatenating (yyyy + mm + dd) and using date formats. Once those are dates you can easily find the smallest date.

Comment: An answer depends very much on what you already have learned. For example since a lot of date comparisons are necessary, this part makes sense in its own method (or use the `Date` class).

Comment: You can basically track the time in mills and grab the largest of the largest of the three.

Comment: maugustoa, are you allowed to use library classes, like for example `LocalDate` as @BasilBourque suggested?

Comment: If you want to compare your nine variables directly, it will be many `if` statements. You need to take into account that the years may be equal and the months different, or years and months equal and days different. Simpler solutions exist. If you can use `LocalDate`, do so. If not, one option is combining a date string in YYYYMMDD format for each booth and comparing the strings. `String.format()` may be useful for building the strings.

Comment: Your code will recognize April 25 2017 as more recent than April 24 2017. It will not recognize April 10 2017 as more recent than March 25 2017 because 10 is not `>=` 25.

Comment: If you’re not allowed to use a standard library class like `LocalDate`, I think I would recommend writing your own date class. The constructor would accept three arguments for year, month and day. The class would either have a method like `isAfter()` for comparing instances in time, or it would implement `Comparable` (if you don’t know what the latter is, ignore it).

Comment: Can I take it from your code snippet that your variables for day, month and year are of primitive type (like `int`) and not `String`?

Answer (score -1):

I think this should solve your purpose

```
Long ver =new Long("" + yyyyverizon + mmverizon + ddverizon); //concatenate e.g. 20131123
Long spr = new Long("" + yyyysprint + mmsprint + ddsprint);
Long att = new Long("" + yyyyatt + mmatt + ddatt);

System.out.println(Math.min(ver, Math.min(spr, att)));
```

Comment: Have you thought about dates with a single digit month or day?

Comment: @Henry that shouldn't be difficult to handle in strings

Comment: why down vote without explanation? if you have any problem with my suggestion you should provide details.

Comment: I did not downvote it, but gave already a reason why this doesn't work. From the question one sees the variables are of integer type. You assume the same or the `"" + ...` is useless. Your method gives wrong results if e.g. the day is less then 10.

Comment: @Henry my down vote comment was not specifically for you. My approach, which I think is better than writing complex if-else nesting or converting to date and then finding the smallest date. If day/month is a single digit it can easily be handled with string concatenation. something like -- (day < 10 ? ("0" + day) : day). I have tried this approach before posting. If you still find it not working I will love to try something else and re-post my answer.

Comment: I suggest String ver = String.format(Locale.ROOT, "%04d%02d%02d", yyyyverizon, mmverizon, ddverizon);` and then comparing the strings. This should take one-digit months and days into account. The use of `Long` objects seems conceptually incorrect and is not necessary.

Comment: Amit, if you want to work with longs, here is a method to convert without resorting to going to string and back: `long ver=yyyyverizon*10000L+mmverizon*100+ddverizon`

Comment: By the way, unless the year is somewhat greater than 200000, your long should fit nicely in an `int` or `Integer`.